# Use grep and map function to sort a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, grep

Given the structure below:

```
my %names = qw ( hanibal lecter Harry Potter INDIANA JONES Sarah connor scarlet O’Hara JAMES Bond );
```

Write a program that builds an array of names based on this list. The resulting array should contain full names (first + last name) in their original capitalization and should be ordered by the last name/first name. When sorting, you must ignore capitalization. 
For reasons unknown, we don’t want people named “Jones” or “Connor” in our list so they should be filtered out.

this is my requirement, and i need to solve this problem using grep, map and sort functions.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us the code you have, and also tell us how it fails to do what you need. An [mcve] helps us to give a much better answer.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with you question: 1) Your title (where you ask to sort) doesn't match the body of the question (where you ask to build an array of names). 2) It's unclear what "building an array of names" means.

Comment: You seem to have some misconceptions. 1) Hashes can't be sorted (though you could obtain the keys of a hash and sort those). 2) Neither `grep` nor `map` sort.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the key and values in your hash are names. So the easiest way to "build an array of names" from your hash is simply:

```
my @names = %names;
```

But that doesn't use `map` or `grep`. So we can (pointlessly) add them.

```
my @names = grep { 1 } map { $_ } %names;
```

I think, perhaps, you should explain what you want in a little more detail.